# VS2013 Update 3 and Azure SDK 2.4 started opening localhost instead of local IP address

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-web-roles, azure-sdk-.net

We just updated Visual Studio 2013 to Update 3 and updated Azure SDK to version 2.4. We select `Use IIS Web Server` and `Use Full Emulator` for the WebRole.

Previously, when we debugged our solutions, they would start up the Azure Emulators, then open the browser with the correct local IP address and port number (e.g. 127.0.0.1:81). If we open another solution and debug it, it would then open the browser with an incremented IP address and new port number (e.g. 127.0.0.2:83).

Now, out of nowhere, after doing these updates, when my coworker and I (two separate computers) try to debug any of our solutions, it opens the browser with "localhost:81". This works fine for the first solution we run (since localhost binds to 127.0.0.1, which is where the site is actually running), but when we run a second solution, it opens with "localhost:83". This obviously doesn't work, because it's mapping to "127.0.0.1:83", when that site actually maps to "127.0.0.2:83".

I checked in the Azure Compute Emulator and see some errors appearing, but not sure what they mean or if they are causing this issue:

```
[MonAgentHost] Error: MA EVENT: 2014-08-25T20:52:09.136Z
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2
[MonAgentHost] Error:     9136
[MonAgentHost] Error:     9016
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SystemEventsListener.dll
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     f795f9c8-6543-4edd-8fef-c36e51e
[MonAgentHost] Error:     systemeventslistener.cpp
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SystemEventsListener::GetEventMetaData
[MonAgentHost] Error:     1312
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2
[MonAgentHost] Error:     The system cannot find the file specified.
[MonAgentHost] Error:     EvtOpenPublisherMetadata failed
[MonAgentHost] Error: MA EVENT: 2014-08-25T20:52:09.136Z
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2
[MonAgentHost] Error:     9136
[MonAgentHost] Error:     9016
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SystemEventsListener.dll
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     f795f9c8-6543-4edd-8fef-c36e51e
[MonAgentHost] Error:     systemeventslistener.cpp
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SystemEventsListener::AnalyzeEvent
[MonAgentHost] Error:     1197
[MonAgentHost] Error:     ffffffff80010008
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     
[MonAgentHost] Error:     Error: Cannot get event message meta data
[MonAgentHost] Error: MA EVENT: 2014-08-25T20:52:09.197Z
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2
[MonAgentHost] Error:     9136
[MonAgentHost] Error:     9016
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SystemEventsListener.dll
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     f795f9c8-6543-4edd-8fef-c36e51e
[MonAgentHost] Error:     systemeventslistener.cpp
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SystemEventsListener::GetEventMetaData
[MonAgentHost] Error:     1312
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2
[MonAgentHost] Error:     The system cannot find the file specified.
[MonAgentHost] Error:     EvtOpenPublisherMetadata failed
[MonAgentHost] Error: MA EVENT: 2014-08-25T20:52:09.197Z
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2
[MonAgentHost] Error:     9136
[MonAgentHost] Error:     9016
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SystemEventsListener.dll
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     f795f9c8-6543-4edd-8fef-c36e51e
[MonAgentHost] Error:     systemeventslistener.cpp
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SystemEventsListener::AnalyzeEvent
[MonAgentHost] Error:     1197
[MonAgentHost] Error:     ffffffff80010008
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     
[MonAgentHost] Error:     Error: Cannot get event message meta data
[MonAgentHost] Error: MA EVENT: 2014-08-25T20:52:13.267Z
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2
[MonAgentHost] Error:     9136
[MonAgentHost] Error:     9016
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SystemEventsListener.dll
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     f795f9c8-6543-4edd-8fef-c36e51e
[MonAgentHost] Error:     systemeventslistener.cpp
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SystemEventsListener::GetEventMetaData
[MonAgentHost] Error:     1312
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2
[MonAgentHost] Error:     The system cannot find the file specified.
[MonAgentHost] Error:     EvtOpenPublisherMetadata failed
[MonAgentHost] Error: MA EVENT: 2014-08-25T20:52:13.267Z
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2
[MonAgentHost] Error:     9136
[MonAgentHost] Error:     9016
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SystemEventsListener.dll
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     f795f9c8-6543-4edd-8fef-c36e51e
[MonAgentHost] Error:     systemeventslistener.cpp
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SystemEventsListener::AnalyzeEvent
[MonAgentHost] Error:     1197
[MonAgentHost] Error:     ffffffff80010008
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     
[MonAgentHost] Error:     Error: Cannot get event message meta data
[MonAgentHost] Error: MA EVENT: 2014-08-25T20:52:13.296Z
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2
[MonAgentHost] Error:     9136
[MonAgentHost] Error:     9016
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SystemEventsListener.dll
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     f795f9c8-6543-4edd-8fef-c36e51e
[MonAgentHost] Error:     systemeventslistener.cpp
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SystemEventsListener::GetEventMetaData
[MonAgentHost] Error:     1312
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2
[MonAgentHost] Error:     The system cannot find the file specified.
[MonAgentHost] Error:     EvtOpenPublisherMetadata failed
[MonAgentHost] Error: MA EVENT: 2014-08-25T20:52:13.296Z
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2
[MonAgentHost] Error:     9136
[MonAgentHost] Error:     9016
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SystemEventsListener.dll
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     f795f9c8-6543-4edd-8fef-c36e51e
[MonAgentHost] Error:     systemeventslistener.cpp
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SystemEventsListener::AnalyzeEvent
[MonAgentHost] Error:     1197
[MonAgentHost] Error:     ffffffff80010008
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     
[MonAgentHost] Error:     Error: Cannot get event message meta data
[MonAgentHost] Error: MA EVENT: 2014-08-25T20:52:16.087Z
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2
[MonAgentHost] Error:     9136
[MonAgentHost] Error:     9016
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SystemEventsListener.dll
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     f795f9c8-6543-4edd-8fef-c36e51e
[MonAgentHost] Error:     systemeventslistener.cpp
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SystemEventsListener::GetEventMetaData
[MonAgentHost] Error:     1312
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2
[MonAgentHost] Error:     The system cannot find the file specified.
[MonAgentHost] Error:     EvtOpenPublisherMetadata failed
[MonAgentHost] Error: MA EVENT: 2014-08-25T20:52:16.087Z
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2
[MonAgentHost] Error:     9136
[MonAgentHost] Error:     9016
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SystemEventsListener.dll
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     f795f9c8-6543-4edd-8fef-c36e51e
[MonAgentHost] Error:     systemeventslistener.cpp
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SystemEventsListener::AnalyzeEvent
[MonAgentHost] Error:     1197
[MonAgentHost] Error:     ffffffff80010008
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     
[MonAgentHost] Error:     Error: Cannot get event message meta data
[MonAgentHost] Error: MA EVENT: 2014-08-25T20:52:16.119Z
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2
[MonAgentHost] Error:     9136
[MonAgentHost] Error:     9016
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SystemEventsListener.dll
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     f795f9c8-6543-4edd-8fef-c36e51e
[MonAgentHost] Error:     systemeventslistener.cpp
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SystemEventsListener::GetEventMetaData
[MonAgentHost] Error:     1312
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2
[MonAgentHost] Error:     The system cannot find the file specified.
[MonAgentHost] Error:     EvtOpenPublisherMetadata failed
[MonAgentHost] Error: MA EVENT: 2014-08-25T20:52:16.119Z
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2
[MonAgentHost] Error:     9136
[MonAgentHost] Error:     9016
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SystemEventsListener.dll
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     f795f9c8-6543-4edd-8fef-c36e51e
[MonAgentHost] Error:     systemeventslistener.cpp
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SystemEventsListener::AnalyzeEvent
[MonAgentHost] Error:     1197
[MonAgentHost] Error:     ffffffff80010008
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     
[MonAgentHost] Error:     Error: Cannot get event message meta data
[MonAgentHost] Error: MA EVENT: 2014-08-25T20:52:18.820Z
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2
[MonAgentHost] Error:     9136
[MonAgentHost] Error:     9016
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SystemEventsListener.dll
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     f795f9c8-6543-4edd-8fef-c36e51e
[MonAgentHost] Error:     systemeventslistener.cpp
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SystemEventsListener::GetEventMetaData
[MonAgentHost] Error:     1312
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2
[MonAgentHost] Error:     The system cannot find the file specified.
[MonAgentHost] Error:     EvtOpenPublisherMetadata failed
[MonAgentHost] Error: MA EVENT: 2014-08-25T20:52:18.820Z
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2
[MonAgentHost] Error:     9136
[MonAgentHost] Error:     9016
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SystemEventsListener.dll
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     f795f9c8-6543-4edd-8fef-c36e51e
[MonAgentHost] Error:     systemeventslistener.cpp
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SystemEventsListener::AnalyzeEvent
[MonAgentHost] Error:     1197
[MonAgentHost] Error:     ffffffff80010008
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     
[MonAgentHost] Error:     Error: Cannot get event message meta data
[MonAgentHost] Error: MA EVENT: 2014-08-25T20:52:18.856Z
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2
[MonAgentHost] Error:     9136
[MonAgentHost] Error:     9016
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SystemEventsListener.dll
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     f795f9c8-6543-4edd-8fef-c36e51e
[MonAgentHost] Error:     systemeventslistener.cpp
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SystemEventsListener::GetEventMetaData
[MonAgentHost] Error:     1312
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2
[MonAgentHost] Error:     The system cannot find the file specified.
[MonAgentHost] Error:     EvtOpenPublisherMetadata failed
[MonAgentHost] Error: MA EVENT: 2014-08-25T20:52:18.856Z
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2
[MonAgentHost] Error:     9136
[MonAgentHost] Error:     9016
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SystemEventsListener.dll
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     f795f9c8-6543-4edd-8fef-c36e51e
[MonAgentHost] Error:     systemeventslistener.cpp
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SystemEventsListener::AnalyzeEvent
[MonAgentHost] Error:     1197
[MonAgentHost] Error:     ffffffff80010008
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     
[MonAgentHost] Error:     Error: Cannot get event message meta data
[MonAgentHost] Error: MA EVENT: 2014-08-25T20:52:21.636Z
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2
[MonAgentHost] Error:     9136
[MonAgentHost] Error:     9016
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SystemEventsListener.dll
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     f795f9c8-6543-4edd-8fef-c36e51e
[MonAgentHost] Error:     systemeventslistener.cpp
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SystemEventsListener::GetEventMetaData
[MonAgentHost] Error:     1312
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2
[MonAgentHost] Error:     The system cannot find the file specified.
[MonAgentHost] Error:     EvtOpenPublisherMetadata failed
[MonAgentHost] Error: MA EVENT: 2014-08-25T20:52:21.636Z
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2
[MonAgentHost] Error:     9136
[MonAgentHost] Error:     9016
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SystemEventsListener.dll
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     f795f9c8-6543-4edd-8fef-c36e51e
[MonAgentHost] Error:     systemeventslistener.cpp
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SystemEventsListener::AnalyzeEvent
[MonAgentHost] Error:     1197
[MonAgentHost] Error:     ffffffff80010008
[fabric] Role state Unhealthy
[fabric] Role state Started
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     
[MonAgentHost] Error:     Error: Cannot get event message meta data
```

I also looked in the Event Viewer under `System` logs, and I see these three errors appearing every time I debug a solution:

`The application '/' belonging to site '1273337584' has an invalid AppPoolId '099a3c29-93de-4169-8a9d-0a8555c5b926' set.  Therefore, the application will be ignored.`

`Site 1273337584 was disabled because the root application defined for the site is invalid. See the previous event log message for information about why the root application is invalid.`

`A process serving application pool '099a3c29-93de-4169-8a9d-0a8555c5b926' terminated unexpectedly. The process id was '9396'. The process exit code was '0xfffffffe'.`

Does anyone have any ideas why this suddenly started happening? Is there a way to get VS2013/Azure back to opening the browser with the correct local IP addresses?

[edit: I have added this as [a bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/956300) at connect.microsoft.com. No replies yet.]